# If the object in the first animation moves within a range constantly, how do I initiate the second animation for the object in particular position?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I want to make a sea level rise up and down originally. When I press the button, it rises from the particular sea level to the top, but I don't know how to do it. Below is my code, thank you!!!

In the css part, instead of setting keyframes "rise" top:290px, is there any other way to express the current sea level?

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="startFunction()">Click</button>
<div class="sea" id="searise"></div>

<style>
  .sea {
    position: absolute;
    height: 650px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #a4c2ef;
    animation: wave 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  
  @keyframes wave {
    0% {
      top: 300px;
    }
    50% {
      top: 290px;
    }
    100% {
      top: 300px;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes rise {
    0% {
      top: 290px;
      height: 650px;
    }
    100% {
      top: 0;
      height: 850px;
    }
  }
</style>
<script>
  function startFunction() {
    var searise = document.getElementById("searise");
    searise.style.animation = "rise 10s forwards";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get current sea level with the help of javascript by reading `offsetTop` property of the sea. to use that info in css, you need to set a custom css property or css variable, so that you use dynamically in css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn" onclick="startFunction()">Click</button>
  <div class="sea" id="searise"></div>

  <style>
    .sea {
      position: absolute;
      height: 650px;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: #a4c2ef;
      animation: wave 3s ease-in-out infinite;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    
    @keyframes wave {
      0% {
        top: 300px;
      }
      50% {
        top: 290px;
      }
      100% {
        top: 300px;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rise {
      0% {
        top: var(--dynamic-top); /*  */
        height: 650px;
      }
      100% {
        top: 0;
        height: 850px;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function startFunction() {
      var searise = document.getElementById("searise");
      searise.style.setProperty("--dynamic-top", `${searise.offsetTop}px`); // 
      searise.style.animation = "rise 10s forwards";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but if I do it without jquery, should I do something like this?
var searise = document.getElementById("searise");
    var seaOffset = searise.offsetTop;
    searise.style.animation = "rise 10s forwards";
    searise.style.setProperty("--dynamic-top", '{seaOffset}px');

Comment: yes, you should.